# Linux Mint stopped booting

Tags: linux-mint

I have been using Linux Mint (Cinnamon) for at least a year. Started with 18.1 and once 18.2 was available I did the upgrade to it. Everything has been working perfectly. Yesterday, when I turned on my computer it won't boot. I can see the grub2 menu, the Linux Mint logo being displayed and then I get a white cursor at the top left corner. Nothing else. I tried editing the grub2 load adding the "`nomodeset grub_gfxmode=1280x1024x24`" but still having the same issue. 
I was able to get to a command line by doing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, able to log in, I ran `sudo apt purge "nvidia-*"` and then doing `startx` starts the GUI. But for some reason I have now to do this every time I boot the computer (without the `sudo apt purge "nvidia-*"`).

More information that may help find the root cause and how to fix it:

`/etc/X11/default-display-manager` says "/usr/sbin/lightdm"

I tried running `sudo systemctl start mdm` but got error "Failed to start mdm.service: Unit mdm service not found".

Update manager says there is no updates.

Running kernel 4.10.0-35.

Dual booting with Windows 7

I need your help to see what is going on and what made it fail, and hopefully be able to restore it (I have several files/configurations that need to preserve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and that worked!
Don't know what this does, but it fixed my problem. Thanks